# Upgrading Neo4J 3.3.4 -> 3.4.0 missing dependency "com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataParam", what is the replacement?

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-databases

When upgrading Neo4J from 3.3.4 to 3.4.0 the dependency "com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataParam" no longer exists. We are using it like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/path/to/api")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response restorePost(@Context HttpServletRequest httpRequest,
                            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream file) {

    return service.processRequest(httpRequest, file);
}
```

Is it another way of doing this in 3.4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After asking this question to the Neo4J support I got this answer:

> Unlike in Neo4j 3.3.5 which includes:
>
> `$NEO4J_HOME/lib/jersey-server-1.19.jar
>   $NEO4J_HOME/lib/jersey-core-1.19.jar
>   $NEO4J_HOME/lib/jersey-multipart-1.19.jar
>   $NEO4J_HOME/lib/jersey-servlet-1.19.jar`
>
> 3.4.0 no longer includes:
>
> `$NEO4J_HOME/lib/jersey-multipart-1.19.jar`
>
> since it is no longer used by the core Neo4j database. However you
>   should be able to simply add a new dependency similar to what is
>   described at
>   https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey.contribs/jersey-multipart/1.9.1
>   then this should address your issue.

So in my scenario this was solved by adding this dependency to our pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>1.19.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Note that the version differs from what is linked in the response from Neo4J. Not sure if the answer is wrong, or if it is because I am testing this on a release candidate. But in my version 3.4.0 RC Neo4J server, the jersey version included is 1.19.3 and not 1.19.1 (check in the "lib" folder of your Neo4J server).

Apart from this you need to make sure that the proper jar's are deployed to your Neo4J plugins folder. In our case we do this with a configuration in maven, but you could also add the dependencies manually. Note that jersey-multipart 1.19.3 is dependent on mimepull 1.9.3, so you need to add both.